# actionListener on jcheckbox

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcheckbox, anonymous-inner-class

I am trying to add an anonymous actionListener to a JCheckBox but having some difficulty in accessing the object I want to update the value with.  I keep getting errors about non final, and then when i change them to be final it complains about other things.
what im trying to do is below (i've removed some of the gui code to make it easier to read):

```
for (FunctionDataObject fdo : wdo.getFunctionDataList())
{
    JLabel inputTypesLabel = new JLabel("Input Types: ");
    inputsBox.add(inputTypesLabel);
    for (int i = 0; i < fdo.getNumberOfInputs(); i++)
    {
        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel(fdo.getInputNames().get(i));
        JComboBox inputTypeComboBox = new JComboBox(getTypes());
        inputTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
             {
                 fdo.getInputTypes().set(i, (String) inputTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
             }
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: I think that issue is hidded in the code that isn't presented, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), there could be mistakes in code concept, not how to set final indicator for anonymous listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a non final variable in an anonymous class. You could slightly modify your code to work around that restriction (I have made `fdo` and `inputTypeComboBox` final and I've also made a final copy of `i`):

```
    for (final FunctionDataObject fdo : wdo.getFunctionDataList()) {
        JLabel inputTypesLabel = new JLabel("Input Types: ");
        inputsBox.add(inputTypesLabel);
        for (int i = 0; i < fdo.getNumberOfInputs(); i++) {
            final int final_i = i;
            JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel(fdo.getInputNames().get(i));
            final JComboBox inputTypeComboBox = new JComboBox(getTypes());
            inputTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fdo.getInputTypes().set(final_i, (String) inputTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code from

```
 inputTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {
             fdo.getInputTypes().set(i, (String) inputTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
         }
    });
```

to

```
final counter = i;
final JComboBox inputTypeComboBox = new JComboBox(getTypes());
final FunctionDataObject finalFDO = fdo;
inputTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {
             finalFDO.getInputTypes().set(counter, (String) inputTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
         }
    });
```

[This](http://geekexplains.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/why-inner-classes-can-access-only-local.html) link explains why you can only access final variables in inner class

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
    for (final FunctionDataObject fdo : wdo.getFunctionDataList()) {
        JLabel inputTypesLabel = new JLabel("Input Types: ");
        inputsBox.add(inputTypesLabel);
        for (int i = 0; i < fdo.getNumberOfInputs(); i++) {
            JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel(fdo.getInputNames().get(i));
            final JComboBox inputTypeComboBox = new JComboBox(getTypes());
            final int index = i;
            inputTypeComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     fdo.getInputTypes().set(index, (String) inputTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem());
                 }
            });
         }
    }
```